# How many JLabels fit in my JPanel

Tags: java, swing, layout

I'm trying to fill a JPanel with a neat grid containing as many JLabels as will fit into the JPanel. The size of the JPanel can vary, and the size of the JLabels depends on the label text, the icon included in the JLabel, and the font being used to render the label text.

```
GridLayout myLayout = new GridLayout();
JPanel myPanel = new JPanel(myLayout);
List<JLabel> myLabels = ...

int panelWidth = myPanel.getWidth();
int panelHeight = myPanel.getHeight();
if (panelWidth == 0 || panelHeight == 0) return;

int maxLabelWidth = 0, maxLabelHeight = 0;
for (JLabel label : myLabels) {
    int labelWidth = ???
    int labelHeight = ???
    if (labelWidth > maxLabelWidth) maxLabelWidth = labelWidth;
    if (labelHeight > maxLabelHeight) maxLabelHeight = labelHeight;
}
// Use panelHeight, panelWidth, maxLabelHeight and maxLabelWidth to compute
// rows and columns available for myLayout
myLayout.setRows(nRows); myLayout.setColumns(nColumns);
for (JLabel label : myLabels) {
    myPanel.add(label);
    // stop if we reach nRows*nColumns labels
}
```

I've tried myPanel.getGraphics().getFontMetrics().getHeight() to get the height of text, but when the font is large and myPanel is small, the text is taller than labelHeight, and the bottom and top get cut off.

I've tried label.getIcon().getIconHeight() to get the height of the icon, but using this value always cuts off the top and bottom of the icons.

I've tried label.getSize() to get the height and width of the JLabel, but that usually returns 0 height and 0 width. I've tried label.getPreferredSize() but that generally returns a value that's too small.

I've tried label.getGraphics().getFontMetrics().stringWidth(label.getText()) to get the width of the string, and then added that to label.getIcon().getIconWidth() and label.getIcon().getIconTextGap() but that comes up with a value a little larger or smaller than label.getPreferredSize(), and in any case still too small - sometimes the label text is cut off at the end.

At one point I tried adding a constant to each width and height; that prevented cut-off text and icons, but of course it left too much blank space around the JLabels. Is there a way to get an accurate size for each JLabel for this usage?

Comment: *"I'm trying to fill a JPanel with a neat grid containing as many JLabels as will fit into the JPanel."* What unusual requirement has this make sense? If there are 15 possible labels, what is the sense of showing only 12? It almost sounds like an XY problem. Given that, I suspect you should look into using a `JList` (in a scroll pane) in which each item displays the icon (possibly scaled down to fit) & pops up a tool tip with full sized icon and complete text when the user points the mouse at it. ..

Comment: .. That provides the best of all worlds in most cases, in that the user can scroll up and down the list, then point at items for full details. If the 'pop up' does not work for a particular use-case, instead put a panel beside the list that shows the details (icon & text) of any item selected from within the list.

Comment: A label's preferred size should be right after `validate()` gets called, say by `pack()`.

Comment: @AndrewThompson In the case of 15 labels and room only for 12, The Design Requirements Handed Down From On High say that a separate control be made available to show other "pages" of labels. A ScrollPane would be a nice solution, except that The Design Requirements dictate otherwise.

Comment: @CatalinaIsland thank you, I will investigate the effect of `validate()` and `pack()` on this problem.

Comment: @RickS: If the "separate control" can't be a scroll bar, you might look at buttons to page back and forth.